# Theatrical Release vs Home Release Differences

Tags: alternate-version, no-country-for-old-men

When I saw No Country for Old Men in the theatre, I *swear* I saw a scene where Llewellyn was crawling through the brush on the river bank **AT NIGHT** (after he came back into the US).

When I recently rewatched it (Netflix Streaming), I was kind of watching it while I was doing other stuff and I missed the incredibly short scene where Lew walks out of the brush in the daytime with the case of money. So for this reason, I thought he didn't have it and I was very confused and thought that Chigurh didn't end up with it either. In retrospect, there are a couple scenes where you clearly see Lew with the case (when he calls Carla Jean). Also when the sheriff re-enters the motel of the Mexican shootout (Chigurh was hiding behind the door). The Sheriff sees the air vent has been taken off the wall, further leading to suggest that Chigurh does in fact end up with the money.

TL;DR - Is there anyone that has the *theatrical* edit of the movie on DVD and can you check to see if I'm insane or if there really was a scene of Lew climbing down by the riverbank at night. Thanks!

Comment: any particular reason for the downvote? I'm new to this site (but not to stack exchange) - am I breaking a rule or suggestion with my question?

Comment: please don't ask **reason for downvotes**. this are not my words, it is advice from this [**comment**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74605/why-did-the-probe-activate-retrorockets-on-a-water-landing#comment121002_74605). I hope it will help you because you are new to this SE.

Comment: @viggity, actually, contrary to what Dhanraj Kumar has stated, it's perfectly acceptable to ask why you're being downvoted if you're looking to improve your question/make it clearer. It's a much bigger sin to downvote for no reason, or without leaving constructive criticism to improve the answer.

Comment: And the comment linked by @DhanrajKumar above was advice specific to a person which cannot be taken out of the rest of its context.